# Convert string with times and math into seconds

Tags: python, math

I want to have a string like these below, and then convert it into seconds. I'm aware that you can't really do math with different time units, I therefore want to convert it to seconds first. Here's a few examples.

- "1d, 25hour and 20 sec."
- "sqrt(20 seconds) * 9 minutes - 12%"

Then the result would be:

- "1d, 1h, 1 min" -> 90 060 seconds

I'm aware that I would need to use the `math` library, and probably the `re` library to get the different elements. Then I'd need to convert all the time units to seconds, before passing it all into an `eval` with the `math` library. Not sure how to though, any help appreciated!

Comment: are there constant tokens? I mean "sec." could also be found as "seconds" or other ways?

Comment: There will be `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. Each with aliases like, hour, h, minute, min, m, second, sec and s.

Comment: make a dictionary `{"hours": 3600, ..., "h": 3600}` including all possible aliases and their corresponding value in seconds

Comment: Yes, that I do have. The problem is however how to make it all into sections, to then be used with math.

Comment: next step use regex-`sub` with callback function. Showing your code will make life easier:)